# Any chance Github Copilot steals closed source code?

Tags: github, github-copilot

I am pretty sure the answer is "no" or we'd hear about it, but wanted to double-check. Does Github Copilot even send any local code to the backend?

Ideally, I'd want an AI autocompletion tool to share proprietary code within an organization, and only there.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

All calculations of GitHub Copilot happen on their Servers, none on your local machine. And if you don't disable telemetry as explained in their FAQ your interaction with Copilot (accepting/rejecting Suggestions) might be used to improve copilot, even tho they say your code will not be used. All this Information can be found in the FAQ: https://github.com/features/copilot (bottom of the page)

There are other competitors to Copilot that offer what you are looking for. Especially AI Learning on proprietary Code for your organization. But I won't disclose any names here since it could be seen as advertisement.

Comment: Great answer, thanks! 

How much do you trust them once you've disabled telemetry? 

I think it's fair to disclose other products in comments. People advertise their own products here all the time. They just add a disclaimer that it's their product. With other products, I've never seen a problem. I think there is a rule against opinion-based questions, but no rule against mentioning products AFAIK. And comments seem fair game for everybody.

Comment: I wouldn't say I distrust Microsoft. But I can understand every Sec person uncomfortable with the idea. 

My company is discussing to use a self-hosted version of tabnine. And even the not self-hosted options have the posebility for private learning and non-cloud suggestions. If you have a more concerned security department this might be a product worth taking a look at.

Comment: Tabnine would be nice, because we are a gitlab shop. How secure is it? AFAICT, it's endorsed, but not owned by Gitlab. Do you feel it's safer than Copilot? How do they compare quality-wise?

Comment: The project FauxPilot is working on a opensource copilot but I have no idea how far they are.